# Can't install new atmosphere package

Tags: meteor, npm-install, atmosphere.js, meteor-packages, meteor-plugin

I'm using Meteor 1.2.1. I can't add [atmosphere](https://atmospherejs.com) package from two days ago until now.

I can add package that later add in other project for example I used simple-schema before and now I can add this successfully without any issue.

I test from two different internet connection and two different laptop but I got this error on console: (for example for [tabular package](https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/tabular))

```
 => Errors while adding packages:             

While downloading aldeed:tabular@1.6.0...:
error: socket hang up
```

I also test using proxy, based on [this page guide](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Meteor-behind-a-proxy) but nothing different. This is my attempt:

```
HTTP_PROXY=http://proxyIP:proxyPort
```

Is it a bug or atmosphere issue or other things?
I test many things in this two days. :cry:

---

**Update:**

I guess maybe it's ISP issue for example with SSL. Is it possible to strict-ssl false for meteor like npm??

Like this on npm:

`npm config set strict_ssl false`

Answer (score 0):

I just tryed adding the tabular package using

```
meteor add aldeed:tabular
```

and it worked fine. So I guess it has nothing to do with atmosphere.

Comment: I do not know if this is possible for meteor, but to be sure if it is an issue with your ISP you could as a first step try to use another connection, for example via a hotspot of your mobile phone.